# When starting a system call, how are user-mode ss and esp saved, e.g. in linux?

Tags: x86, linux-kernel, system-calls

I know user-mode ss/esp should be saved into the kernel-mode stack for later restore.

The question is that to locate kernel-mode stack, ss/esp have to be loaded with the corresponding kernel-mode values first. Now it seems to me that user-mode ss/esp have been flushed. Then how does the hardware/system retrieve the user-mode ss/esp?

Are user-mode ss and esp saved in some temporary places? Or the operation is supported by x86 circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what happens with the instruction pointer. Clearly there must be some hardware support in there somewhere.

Putting aside modern "fast system call" techniques (I'll return to this later), note that a system call is requested by just issuing a specific software interrupt with certain processor registers set up appropriately. So what happens then is down to the interrupt hardware in the processor.

When an interrupt occurs, the processor automatically pushes various registers and other information (things like the instruction pointer, and other stuff that could be modified even before the handler gets a chance to save them) onto the kernel stack. Additionally, if the processor is currently *not* in kernel mode, it pushes the stack pointer and stack segment register onto the kernel stack and transitions to kernel mode, executing the interrupt handler.

Now if we look at "fast system calls" (the SYSENTER instruction), we note that it requires some machine state registers to be already set up, and it *doesn't save state* (this is part of what makes it faster than issuing an interrupt). The calling code is responsible for placing in the unclobbered registers the data that the kernel needs in order to execute the system call, and the data it needs to return to its original state.

Comment: It makes sense to me. For CS/EIP, I think there should also be some hardware support. When some "fault" happens, the current CS/EIP already points to the "next" instruction, while the original faulting CS/EIP have to be retrieved and saved in kernerl-mode stack to re-execute the same instruction after the fault handling. To retrieve the original CS/EIP, there should be some hardware support also, right?

Comment: @SetTimer: I'm not entirely sure how it all works under the hood - but yes, it's likely that EIP is carried through the pipeline along with the other necessary data for the instruction. I doubt CS would be handled the same way though - it would be a lot of transistors in order to carry it through, and it's not a very common case for it to be modified, so I would guess modifying CS just stalls the pipeline instead, similar to a branch misprediction. But modern processors are very complex and I don't know for sure either way.